# Using the new Next.js Image component with Material UI

Tags: material-ui, next.js, nextjs-image

In Material UI the components that display images have a parameter for the image. eg:

```
<Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" />
```

In Next.js v10 there is a new `Image` component that automatically scales images: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image

Has anyone figured out how to use the new `Image` component with Material UI?

Answer (score 14):

I am able to use it like this and it works well. I hope it will be helpful.

```
<Avatar className={className}>
  <Image src={src || placeholder} alt={alt} layout="fill" />
</Avatar>
```

Comment: Please use the `fill` prop instead of `layout="fill"` from now on. The layout prop is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

import image_1 from "/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" //locate image

then just replace

src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg"

to

src={image_1.src}